# Why is the next line not executing C++

Tags: c++, arrays, char, ifstream

I have attached my full source code of my program that can open a `.txt` file. It doesn't execute after the `cout << length`. I am trying to store the `.txt` file information in memory by using an array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

char filename[128];
char file[10][250];
int count;
int length;
string line;

int main ()
{
    int count = 0;
    int length = 0;
    cout << "Filename: ";
    cin.clear();
    cin.getline(filename, sizeof(filename));
    string new_inputfile(filename);
    ifstream inputfiles (new_inputfile.c_str());
    if(!inputfiles.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File could not be opened. \n ";
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i=0; getline(inputfiles,line); i++)
        {
            length++;
        }

        cout << length;
//      char file[length][250]; <- How can I create the array based on the length variable?
// CODE DOES NOT EXECUTE AFTER THIS.
        while(!inputfiles.eof() && (count<10))
        {
            inputfiles.getline(file[count],250);
            count++;
        }

        for(int i=0; i < count; i++)
        {
            cout << file[i] << endl;
        }

    }
    inputfiles.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Also, since `file[]` is char, say for example `file[1]` contained the char `Name=Mike`, how do I strip off everything before the `=`. I want just `Mike`. I know with `string`, I can use `substr()` method, but I don't know for `char`.

Comment: Why don't you use `getline(cin, new_inputfile);` directly and skip the middle man?

Comment: file is not a `char` it's a `char array` big difference.

Comment: @NeilKirk What do you mean? Where do I put `getline(cin, new_inputfile)`?

Comment: Instead of `cin.getline(filename, sizeof(filename)); string new_inputfile(filename);` you have `string new_inputfile; getline(cin, new_inputfile);`

Comment: @NeilKirk Thanks. How do I store the line as I go along? I heard you can do it without arrays. Like my first line in my `txt` file is `Name=Mike` and I want to set my name variable to `Mike`. My second line is `Age=10` and I want to set my age variable to `10`

Comment: `while (getline(stream, string)) { parse string }`

Answer (score 3):

This is horribly wasteful way to count number of lines in a file.

```
for (int i=0; getline(inputfiles,line); i++) // i is also completely useless here
{
     length++;
}
```

You're reading the whole file only to throw everything away and start again! And after this loop is done, `inputfiles.eof()` will be `true` and you'll never enter neither the next `while` loop nor the last `for` loop (because `i == count`). Execution skips directly to `inputfiles.close()` and then you return from `main`.

I suggest you work on the `line` string as you go:

```
for ( ; getline(inputfiles, line); )
{
     // do stuff with line and ditch the global char arrays
}
```

If you want store the lines for later, well, just save them :) The easiest thing to do is to use a [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::vector<std::string> all_them_lines;
while (getline(file, line) all_them_lines.emplace_back(line);
```

There, the entire file is now saved in `all_them_lines`, line by line. You can access them just like you would in an array, like `all_them_lines[0]`. You also don't need to know the number of lines beforehand - vectors expand automatically when you add stuff to them.

Now to parse a line and extract formatted input from it, check out what [`stringstream` class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) has to offer.

Comment: thanks. so how do I store the line as I go along? I heard you can do it without arrays. Like my first line in my `txt` file is `Name=Mike` and I want to set my `name` variable to `Mike`. My second line is `Age=10` and I want to set my `age` variable to 10

Comment: @user4167396 I expanded the answer a little.

Comment: Thanks :). Is there way of reading a file, not storing the line but storing the line into the variables. For example, if the first line in my `txt` file is `Name=Mike` and I want to set my `name` variable to `Mike`. My second line is `Age=10` and I want to set my `age` variable to `10`. I intend on creating a `setName` and `setAge` method to store the lines

Comment: Yes, there is. I would love if you could figure that part out by yourself, though :) Hint: You can do `int age; cin >> age;`. You can do the same with `ifstream` object instead of `cin`.

Comment: what about the next line? Every line will have a new value and thus will need a new variable. Please help me, it will mean a lot to me

Comment: Use vectors. It's an array, and it's also a template. You can have a `vector<int>` or `vector<char>` or `vector<string>`. That's pretty neat, innit? [Here's an example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d8f86c55c7f2750) that you can play with. Now you need to try stuff by yourself, I can't do all the work for you. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

You asked:

> ```
> //      char file[length][250]; <- How can I create the array based on the length variable?
> ```

Declare `file` as:

```
char (*file)[250] = NULL;
```

and then,

```
file = new char[length][250];
```

Make sure you call `delete [] file` before the end of the function.

You said:

> ```
> // CODE DOES NOT EXECUTE AFTER THIS.
> ```

You can [rewind the stream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) and start reading from it again.

```
    inputfiles.seekg(0);
    count = 0;
    while(!inputfiles.eof())
    {
        inputfiles.getline(file[count],250);
        count++;
    }
```

Comment: @MattMcNabb, I appreciate the comment. Answering the OP's question to the point makes more sense to me some times than suggesting a different but better approach. Some times I do suggest a different approach. For this question, I felt answering the question to the point made more sense.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "to the point". `char file[length][250]` was illegal and has to be replaced by some legal code.

Comment: My suggestion corrects that problem. It suggests the minimal changes to the OP's code to make the code legal. That's what I mean by answering "to the point".